# How to setup 301 redirections in GCP load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redirect, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

I've setup a static website on GCP using [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website). So I have a bucket and a load balancer.

I'm trying to setup URL redirections in the load balancer to avoid BC breaks on old URLs. I want an user arriving to https://example.org/foo to be redirected to https://example.org/bar. I have a dozen redirections like this to setup.

Is there a way to configure that in the load balancer? Or anywhere else?

I've searched in the routing rules, but I'm expecting a "from" field where I could enter "/foo" and a "destination" field where I could enter "/bar", but I got this:

[image]

Or should I use the YAML Path matcher? But I can't find any example of this basic case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility of **URL redirection** in **GCP Load balancer** and from the information provided by you it is observed that a **bucket** and a **Global HTTPs Load balancer** were created in your environment.

To proceed with the URL redirection, you can add **configuration** to a **URL map** so that the map routes traffic to the appropriate service.

Replace the **host** and **path** as per the requirement in the below configuration related to url redirection.

```
urlRedirect:
  hostRedirect: "new-host-name.com" # Omit to keep the requested host
  pathRedirect: "/new-path" # Omit to keep the requested path; mutually exclusive to prefixRedirect
  prefixRedirect: "/newPrefix" # Omit to keep the requested path; mutually exclusive to pathRedirect
  redirectResponseCode: FOUND
  stripQuery: True
```

For more information please refer to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-global-traffic-mgmt#configure_a_url_redirect).

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this way, but I couldn't figure out what I was supposed to put in "defaultService".

Thanks to your answer, I've retried, and using "global/backendBuckets/<the name of my backend bucket>" was the thing I am supposed to do.

Thank you!